# Resize btrfs filesystem to the minimum size in a single step

Tags: filesystems, btrfs

How do I resize a btrfs filesystem to the minimum possible size in a single step?

I only want to `dd` the smallest amount of data possible, and want to use `dd` since `btrfs send` is progressively slower the more snapshots there are.

`btrfs filesystem resize` has a `max` argument, but no `min` argument.

If I try to resize more than the free space available, I get a message like:

```
ERROR: unable to resize '/media/backup-alt': No space left on device
```

I've been progressively resizing downwards in steps of decreasing size (eg passing arguments `-128G` `-64G`, `-32G`, ...) but this is a time consuming convergence on a solution.

Is there a way to shrink to minimum in a single step?

Comment: **Note**: you'll need to change the UUID of the duplicate before mounting *either* filesystem again, or you'll get filesystem corruption!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The best solution I've come across so far is to get the minimum free space (using `-b` for bytes):

```
sudo btrfs filesystem usage -b /mountpoint
```

> ```
>    Free (estimated):              71890542592 (min: 71890542592)
> ```

And then resize by the negative of the `min` amount:

```
sudo btrfs filesystem resize -71890542592 /mountpoint
```

Alternatively, if there is a big difference between the min free and the unallocated, you may choose to use (unallocated * 0.9) since resizing by the exact unallocated bytes seems to fail.

You can then repeatedly shrink by small amounts until the resize fails:

```
while sudo btrfs filesystem resize -200M /mountpoint; do true; done
```

This is not exactly a single step, but at least mostly automated. The loop by itself could be a single step, but it will probably take longer doing small incremental resizes rather than initially shrinking by a large chunk.

Comment: Hi, can you please Edit your answer to add the output of your `sudo btrfs filesystem usage -b /mountpoint` ?

Comment: @SebMa I can't remember which filesystem this was now... what do you find unclear?

Comment: Which line in `sudo btrfs f u -b /mountpoint` do you pick the `71890542592` from ? Can you please give another output from any btrfs currently use ?

Comment: @SebMa there is only one line in the output that contains `Free`, and one `min` value... Still, I updated for great karma.

Comment: Exactly what I wanted so there is no ambiguity possible.

Answer (score 1):

An easier solution to your problem would be to use `partclone.btrfs` instead if `dd`, it's a partition cloning and imaging tool that automatically skips unused blocks for supported filesystems (including BTRFS), so no resizing needed.

https://www.partclone.org (GPL-2.0)